# Disable recent Chrome zoom control/panel

Tags: macos, google-chrome, osx-snow-leopard, zoom

MacOSX Snow Leopard, current version of Chrome

For the past few months, Chrome responds to a zoom request (`Command +`) by putting up a small "panel" or popup in the top right of its window.

[image: Chrome zoom panel]

That panel responds to a space bar press by zooming out.

So I get stuck with this:

1. `Command +` => Zoom in (good)
2. `Spacebar` press intended to scroll down the page => zooms out (bad)

Of course, I can wait until the panel disappears after a few seconds.

Is there a Chrome setting that will disable the panel or set it disappear much more quickly and automatically?

Comment: I have the same configuration of you, but not the problem. Try looking elsewhere…